# BitTorrent Sync open source alternnative

Tags: sync, bittorrent

BitTorrent Sync is great. But I wish to use it for my docs and passwords.
BitTorrent was hacked recently 
http://forum.ragezone.com/f10/bittorrent-source-dns-reward-948810/

So it is possible that key from my folder leaked.

I wish to have open source alternative.
I wish to understand risks and control all keys myself.

Comment: Have you searched for an alternative? What have you found?

Comment: The problem is that I found sites that offer alternative like Dropbox, Box.com. From other hand I found developer talks willing to develop it. Even in language like Go. I have not found what I looked.

Comment: Then please update your post with what you have looked at, what did and did not work, and provide more specific detail on what you want help with. At this moment your question looks like it's asking for a product recommendation [which is off-topic on this site](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).